# Upper and Lower bounds on the nth prime number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know from papers like Dusarts's that $$n\left(\ln n +\ln \ln n -1+ \frac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}-\frac{\ln^2 \ln n -6 \ln \ln n +12}{2 \ln^2 n}\right) \leq p_n \leq n\left(\ln n +\ln \ln n -1+ \frac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}-\frac{\ln^2 \ln n -6 \ln \ln n +10}{2 \ln^2 n}\right) $$

But could any one give and explicit number $n_0$ for which for all $n \geq n_0$ the above inequalities hold true ?

It does not have to be the smallest one, also if there is way, could you please show me how to get this number

I read a paper that estimate that the $n_0 \approx 3.9*10^{31}$ under the R.H.
if we don't assume R.H. could we still have $n_0 \ll 10^{100}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: These bounds are much tighter than the one mentioned in Wikipedia! Did the paper mentioned a proven bound (not assuming RH) ?

Comment: My guess is that $n_0=10^{100}$ is sufficient

Comment: @peter yes,search for juan and toulisse paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03651), Christian Axler shows that $$p_n\ge n\left(\ln n +\ln \ln n -1+ \dfrac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}-\dfrac{\ln^2 \ln n -6 \ln \ln n +11.508}{2 \ln^2 n}\right)$$ for all $n\ge 2$
And, $$p_n \leq n\left(\ln n +\ln \ln n -1+ \frac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}-\frac{\ln^2 \ln n -6 \ln \ln n +10.667}{2 \ln^2 n}\right)$$
for all $n\ge 46\ 254\ 381$
I have to admit that I can't read and check all of it, because although the proof doesn't seem to require any complex analysis, it involves pretty heavy calculation.

Comment: The problem with this: low-bound margin for small n-th are terrible with this. You'd be better off with a completely different solution for low bounds when N is below 46 254 381. Here's one that I use: `min = n * (ln + lnLn - 1) + (n * lnLn - 2.1 * n) / ln` - it is way more accurate.