# The most accurate estimate for the nth prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$\pi(n)$ counts how many primes are less than or equal to $n$. The most accurate estimate I know for the range of $n$ where it is not possible to compute the answer exactly is

$$\pi(n) \approx \operatorname{li}(n) - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{li}(\sqrt{n})$$

But what is the most accurate estimate for the value of the $n$th prime?

In case I am using the wrong terminology, I am looking for a practically computable formula that gives a value which is as close as possible to the true value.

I could write code to use the estimate for $\pi(n)$ to search for this. Is there another similarly accurate formula?

Comment: For me an estimate is an upper or lower bound. For this, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870327/upper-and-lower-bounds-on-the-nth-prime-number), for example, with $$p_n \leq n\left(\ln n +\ln \ln n -1+ \frac{\ln \ln n -2}{\ln n}-\frac{\ln^2 \ln n -6 \ln \ln n +10.667}{2 \ln^2 n}\right)$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde what's the right word for a formula which is as close as possible to the correct value?

Comment: The right word for such a formula is an *exact* formula, which differs by $0$ from the true value. Like Rademacher's formula for $p(n)$, the number of partitions, or Riemann's formula for $\pi(n)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I mean a formula that is computable in practice.

Comment: [Riemann's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html) has been computed in praxis. The zeros of the Riemann zeta function have been computed in praxis up to billions of billions.

Comment: The li-approximation can a bit be refined with some additional terms, but for huge $n$ we probably cannot do significantly better. Note that without assuming the Riemann hypothesis we have a much smaller guaranteed accuracy.

Comment: @Peter what are the additional terms?

Comment: Grimm's conjecture is $$g_n<n$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee could you say a bit more about that please

Comment: Grimm's conjecture is: in a set of consecutive composites, there exists a bijection to prime factors. Therefore, the gap between primes, is at most the number of primes before the gap. Or the conjecture has counterexamples.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee that's cool. Does it imply an exact estimate I could compare to the true value?

Comment: The first n-1 gaps sum to at most (n-1)n/2 and you have have to add n+1 to it to get the primes and the number 1 so roughly lower than ((n+2)(n-1)+2)/2 but it's a ways off seeing as all odd terms must technically be even.

Comment: The prime gaps have nothing to do with determining the $n$ th prime. Moreover, the sequence of prime gaps is to all we know utterly chaotic.

Comment: $$p_n=2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} g_n$$ so yes they do @Peter.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee :) I think , you know what I mean. Noone would sum up all prime gaps to find , say , the $10^{20}$ th prime.

Comment: No but it like most conjectures give rise to estimates.

Answer (score 1):

For different ranges of $n$, finding the exact $n$th prime rigorously and quickly should be done using different techniques. For all small $n$ (say less than $10^{10}$), it's hard to do much better than an optimized version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

For larger $n$, the space requirements of sieves become problematic. It instead becomes better to explicitly compute $\pi(n)$ using variations of the [Meissel-Lehmer-Lagarias-Miller-Odylzko-Deleglise-Rivat](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf) method. See [Staple's thesis](https://dalspace.library.dal.ca/handle/10222/60524) for recent state of the art and a comparison of analytic and combinatorial methods.

In practice, it is possible to compute $\pi(X)$ with approximate time complexity $X^{2/3}$ and space complexity $X^{1/3}$. (I'm ignoring logs, but at this size logs matter. Staple's thesis saves a log factor from earlier methods). This suggests that a particularly dedicated, expensive effort might be able to find the $n$th prime for $n < 10^{30}$, say — though such effort might take on the order of a hundred thousand CPU-core years.

In principle, for larger $n$ the analytic method of [Lagarias and Odlyzko](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/arch/analytic.pi.of.x.pdf) is faster. But in practice there are very large constants in the asymptotic analysis. In theory, one can compute $\pi(X)$ in roughly $X^{1/2}$ time and $X^{1/4}$ space, though in practice the omitted constants (and log factors) have meant that this method has not yet been faster than the combinatorial options above.

For still larger $n$, one needs a new idea.

Comment: Wikipedia list values for pi(n) up to 10^29. The 10^30th prime would be around 75 x 10^30. 750 times larger, about 80 times harder. So it can be done with deep pockets.

Comment: If you want a table, pi(n) for many values reasonably close together, say k x 10^27 for 1 <= k <= 1000, can be calculated faster than 1000 individual values.

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting answer. I am however interested in getting as accurate an answer as possible when it is not possible to compute the answer exactly

Comment: Also, my question is about $p_n$, the nth prime, and not $\pi(n)$.

Comment: @Simd If $n$ is not too large, you can find the $n$ th prime by applying binary search , if the prime counting function can be calculated fast enough. But I agree your other point that you want the best estimate if $n$ is too large. This is hard to say since further refinements permanently occur.

Comment: A good answer apart from the last part.

Comment: Using the simple li-approximation and applying binary search produces so good estimates (assuming the Riemann hypothesis) that this should be good enough for every purpose that comes into my mind. Which merit would have an even better estimate of , say , the $2^{200}$ th prime ?

Comment: @Simd This answer is also about $p_n$. But the fastest way I know to compute $p_n$ for large $n$ is to actually compute $\pi(n)$.

Comment: +1. The anonymous down-voter was here too, and, as usual, left no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-An spectacular formula giving exactly the $n^{th}$ prime was appeared in $1964$. In the link below figure C.P. Williams as the author. I remember I read this in a small peruvian magazine and I believed the author was a peruvian really. It is the reason I am not sure that Williams was the author.
$$n^{th}\space \text {prime }=1+\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}\left\lfloor\left(\frac nD\right)^{\frac 1n}\right\rfloor$$ where $$D=\sum_{j=1}^i\left\lfloor\cos\left(\frac{(j-1)!+1)\pi}{j}\right)^2\right\rfloor$$.

https://youtu.be/j5s0h42GfvM

In those times (the $60$'s) there were no computers for public use, so the formula could not be verified. But currently it has been possible to verify the accuracy up to certain limits, naturally, of the formula.

Comment: Seems to be the sum of $2^n$ terms? It would be faster to compute the answer exactly wouldn't it?

Comment: @Simd . Yes.  You need to sum  $2^{48}$ terms to find that $p_{48}=223.$ Another exact but arithmetically impractical one is Ghandhi's Formula:  Let $\mu$ be the Mobius function. Let $p\ge 3$ be prime. Let $Q$ be the product of the primes less than $p$. Then $p$ is uniquely determined by $1<2^p(S-1/2)<2$ where $S=\sum_{d|Q}\frac {\mu(d)}{1+2^d}.$ The trick is that $S=\sum_{(gcd(n.Q)=1)}\,2^{-n}$ is more than $1/2+2^p$ and not more than $1/2+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-p-2n}.$

Comment: In my previous comment , the denominator $1+2^d$ in the definition of $S$ should be $-1+2^d.$

Answer (score 1):

A quick and fairly accurate (under RH, at least) estimate for the n-th prime is the inverse logarithmic integral $\operatorname{li}^{-1}$. The error is on the order of square-root, which is better than any of the estimates of the form n log n(1 + 1/log n + ...).

Comment: Is there a readily computable inverse for $\operatorname{li}(x) + \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{li}(\sqrt{x})$ (which I assume is more accurate)?

Comment: You can invert it with standard techniques (say, the secant method). But it's not entirely clear that you'll get a better approximation, there are known to be large (roughly sqrt-sized) oscillations in the error term.

Comment: I don't know when $\operatorname{li}(n)$ is a better approximation. I tested the inverse for $n$ equals $10^1, 10^2, \dots, 10^{18}$ and the ratio of the distance of $\operatorname{li}(n)$  to the true value compared to the distance of  $\operatorname{li}(n) - \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{li}(\sqrt{n})$ to the true value is 8.0
3.5
4.87
13.85
10.8
3.13
1.63
215.93
4.44
6.94
3.15
4.44
4.68
38.24
17.68
7.24
9.39
10.84

Comment: In other words, $\operatorname{li}(n)$ is between $63\%$ and a factor of 216 times further from the true value.

Comment: I mean the ratio of the inverse of li etc It's the inverse of li that is between 63% and a factor of 256 further away

Comment: It is known that li(x) = pi(x) infinitely often (search for Skewes's number), so the inverse li will be within 1 infinitely often. It may very well be the case that li(x) - li(sqrt(x))/2 is better on average, but I don't know if that's been proven.

Comment: If the crossing number is around $100^{300}$ then maybe my "improved" estimate is better up to then.